# Is there any Visual Studio Code code formatter that keeps empty lines untouched?

Tags: line, autoformatting

I just started working with Visual Studio Code, and one of the things I REALLY miss is auto-formatting code while keeping more than one empty line.

Especially in my SCSS-Files I like to have three empty lines between code blocks for different page compontents and modifiers, so I can "fast-scan" through my partials without actually reading all of the selectors. I know that "clean code" is supposed to have just one empty line between selectors, but especially in SCSS-files whitespace comes free, and it drastically improves readability (at least for me).

Auto-formatters like prettier or beautify seem to be pretty opinionated concerning emtpy lines - whenever they find more than one, they erase them. And I didn't find a way to stop them from doing so yet.

Is there any way of using prettier or beautify whitout loosing extra empty lines that I just didn't figure out? Or are there any auto-formatters for VSC that don't remove my exra empyt lines?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, www.superuser.com may help.

Comment: Thank you @RubyRube, I think I will try that :)